# The prefix "ldaptive" for element is not bound

Tags: xml, xsd, ldap, xml-namespaces, cas

I am new to implementing CAS and am having some issues getting it set up to use LDAP. Currently it is returning the error

> The prefix "ldaptive" for element "ldaptive:ad-authenticator" is not bound.

when starting.

As seen in my code, I believe I implemented what was proposed as a fix [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jasig-cas-user/ldaptive%7Csort:relevance/jasig-cas-user/fIn4Fk5eRHI/SmchuoCoBQAJ) but this did not fix the issue.

The code for the deployerConfigContext.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
       http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext
       http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext-1.1.0.xsd
       http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext.xsd">


    <util:map id="authenticationHandlersResolvers">
        <entry key-ref="proxyAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver" />
        <entry key-ref="primaryAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="primaryPrincipalResolver" />
        <entry key-ref="ldapAuthenticationHandler" value="#{null}" />
    </util:map>


    <util:list id="authenticationMetadataPopulators">
        <ref bean="successfulHandlerMetaDataPopulator" />
        <ref bean="rememberMeAuthenticationMetaDataPopulator" />
    </util:list>


    <bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.NamedStubPersonAttributeDao"
          p:backingMap-ref="attrRepoBackingMap" />


    <alias name="acceptUsersAuthenticationHandler" alias="primaryAuthenticationHandler" />
    <alias name="personDirectoryPrincipalResolver" alias="primaryPrincipalResolver" />


    <util:map id="attrRepoBackingMap">
        <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
        <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" />
        <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
        <entry>
            <key><value>memberOf</value></key>
            <list>
                <value>faculty</value>
                <value>staff</value>
                <value>org</value>
            </list>
        </entry>
    </util:map>


    <bean id="ldapAuthenticationHandler"
         class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler"
         p:principalIdAttribute="sAMAccountName"
         c:authenticator-ref="authenticator">
       <property name="principalAttributeMap">
          <map>
              <entry key="displayName" value="name" />
              <entry key="mail" value="email" />
              <entry key="memberOf" value="membership" />
          </map>
       </property>
    </bean>


    <alias name="serviceThemeResolver" alias="themeResolver" />


    <alias name="jsonServiceRegistryDao" alias="serviceRegistryDao" />


    <alias name="defaultTicketRegistry" alias="ticketRegistry" />


    <alias name="ticketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy" alias="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" />
    <alias name="multiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy" alias="serviceTicketExpirationPolicy" />


    <alias name="anyAuthenticationPolicy" alias="authenticationPolicy" />
    <alias name="acceptAnyAuthenticationPolicyFactory" alias="authenticationPolicyFactory" />


    <bean id="auditTrailManager"
          class="org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager"
          p:entrySeparator="${cas.audit.singleline.separator:|}"
          p:useSingleLine="${cas.audit.singleline:false}"/>


    <alias name="neverThrottle" alias="authenticationThrottle" />


    <util:list id="monitorsList">
        <ref bean="memoryMonitor" />
        <ref bean="sessionMonitor" />
    </util:list>


    <ldaptive:ad-authenticator id="authenticator"
        ldapUrl="${ldap.url}"
        userFilter="${ldap.authn.searchFilter}"
        bindDn="${ldap.managerDn}"
        bindCredential="${ldap.managerPassword}"
        allowMultipleDns="${ldap.allowMultipleDns:false}"
        connectTimeout="${ldap.connectTimeout}"
        validateOnCheckOut="${ldap.pool.validateOnCheckout}"
        failFastInitialize="true"
        blockWaitTime="${ldap.pool.blockWaitTime}"
        idleTime="${ldap.pool.idleTime}"
        baseDn="${ldap.baseDn}"
        maxPoolSize="${ldap.pool.maxSize}"
        minPoolSize="${ldap.pool.minSize}"
        validatePeriodically="${ldap.pool.validatePeriodically}"
        validatePeriod="${ldap.pool.validatePeriod}"
        prunePeriod="${ldap.pool.prunePeriod}"
        useSSL="${ldap.use.ssl:false}"
        subtreeSearch="${ldap.subtree.search:true}"
        useStartTLS="${ldap.useStartTLS}" />


    <alias name="defaultPrincipalFactory" alias="principalFactory" />
    <alias name="defaultAuthenticationTransactionManager" alias="authenticationTransactionManager" />
    <alias name="defaultPrincipalElectionStrategy" alias="principalElectionStrategy" />
    <alias name="tgcCipherExecutor" alias="defaultCookieCipherExecutor" />
</beans>
```

The page where the ldaptive prefix comes from seems to longer host it and I have been unable to find where I should be pulling this from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
xmlns:ldaptive="http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext"
```

to your `beans` root element to eliminate your error.

Note also that `@xsi:schemaLocation` should take namespace XSD ***pairs***, and it looks like you have an odd number of entries in yours.  Use this pair for the namespace associated with the `adaptive:` namespace prefix:

```
http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext 
http://www.ldaptive.org/schema/spring-ext-1.2.0.xsd
```

Comment: Please ask a new question, being sure to include a [mcve].  Thanks.

Comment: @acvcu:  You too must ask a new question and provide a [mcve], not try to initiate new questions within the comments to an answer.  Thank you.